# adjust the height of a vuetify item

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am creating a simple table with vuetify and it turns out that when adding the **v-radio-group** component, the elements in the row are not adjusted to the height, so this causes the table to look ugly.

what property could i use to make the cols all fit to the same height.
I have looked in several places, even in the documentation and I do not see anything like it.

component:

```
          <template>
        <v-container>
          <v-row class="text-center" no-gutters>
            <v-col v-for="(item, index) in headers" v-bind:key="index">
              <v-card v-if="item" :key="index" class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                {{ item.nombre }}
              </v-card>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>

          <div v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:key="index">
            <v-row no-gutters class="text-center"
            align="center"
            >
              <v-col
              align-self="center"
              >
                <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                  {{ item.nombre }}
                </v-card>
              </v-col>
              <v-col>
                <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                  {{ item.cantidad }}
                </v-card>
              </v-col>
              <v-col offset-md="12">
                <v-card outlined tile>
                  <v-radio-group v-model="radioGroup">
                    <v-radio
                      v-for="n in 2"
                      :key="n"
                      :label="`Radio ${n}`"
                      :value="n"
                    ></v-radio>
                  </v-radio-group>
                </v-card>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>

            
          </div>
        </v-container>
      </template>

      <script>
      export default {
        name: "HelloWorld",
        data() {
          return {
            optRadio: [
            { nombre: "Bueno", value: 1}, 
            { nombre: "Malo", value: 2}, 

            ],
            headers: [
              { nombre: "Descripcion", value: "descripcion" },
              { nombre: "Cantidad", value: "cantidad" },
              { nombre: "estado", value: "state" },
            ],
            items: [
              { nombre: "RADIO", cantidad: 1, state: 1 },
              { nombre: "FRONTAL", cantidad: 10, state: 0 },
              { nombre: "PARLANTES", cantidad: 100, state: 2 },
              { nombre: "ENCENDEDOR", cantidad: 100, state: 2 },
              { nombre: "CENICERO", cantidad: 100, state: 2 },
              { nombre: "TAPETES", cantidad: 100, state: 2 },
            ],
          };
        },
      };
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key here is applying correct flex attributes to your grid system.

First you'd have to instruct your colums to place content vertically, not horizontally: `<v-col class="d-flex flex-column"`

Then, instruct the cards within to grow in the available vertical height: `<v-card class="pa-2 flex-grow-1 d-flex"  outlined tile>`. To get the content centered within the card, add these two flex helpers to the card as well:  `align-center justify-center`

Documentation [HERE](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/#flex-grow-and-shrink)
Codepen solution [HERE](https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/oNWEBYe)